# Safari autocomplete for cc-exp not working

Tags: html, autocomplete, safari, autofill

I am trying to get autocomplete on a creditcard form to work properly in Safari, however it seems to completely ignore the autocompletion for expiration date. Whether I use cc-exp or separate cc-exp-month/cc-exp-year, neither is working. The autocomplete for cc-name and cc-number are working properly though, as are things working properly in Chrome.

I have been able to bring the issue down to a very simple example:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="cc-name" placeholder="name" />
  <input type="text" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="number" />
  <input type="text" autocomplete="cc-exp" placeholder="expiration" />
  <input type="text" autocomplete="cc-csc" placeholder="cvc" />
</form>
```

What am I missing here? I already tried the older syntax using ID's, names and x-autocompletetype. Neither with any success. Tested on Safari 7 till 10, so this issue seems to be around for a while, or I am really missing something obvious?

(note: to test the example above, make sure you are visiting this page over https, else it would not work anyway)

Comment: Same problem here.  Seems like safari bug

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, never found the solution for this. It makes me think I am doing something wrong as this is an issue in so many Safari browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a solution to this and noticed that on an older form, where I don't even have the autocomplete attribute, it works. The difference between the forms is that on the older form I am using 2 drop-down fields (SELECT tags) for expiry month and year in MM and YYYY formats.

After playing with different options, I concluded that Safari wants 2 separate fields, one for MM and one for YYYY. I now have 2 text fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="CCExpiryMonth" id="CCExpiryMonth" value="" placeholder="MM" autocomplete="cc-exp">
<input type="text" name="CCExpiryYear" id="CCExpiryYear" value="" placeholder="YYYY" autocomplete="cc-exp">
```

This works in Safari.

Comment: From Review: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53501982/edit) your answer and fix it instead of posting several comments to it. Afterwards, remove your comments from the answer. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What about using `cc-exp-month` and `cc-exp-year` for the "autocomplete" values?